# how to save user token after every request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, jwt, token

I have a problem relate to saving token, I have asked some developers and they told me that I shouldn't save my token in localStorage or in Browser
I'm building a react app, so every time the user goes from page to another page I have to reload user information using that token.
My question how to save that token so I can call that token every time I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using Local Storage because it's available to other 3rd party scripts and is susceptible to XSS attacks.

Instead, store it in an **httpOnly cookie** where it will be safe from potentially harmful JavaScript scripts.

https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/
https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04

Comment: Is There a Way to retrieve it, I mean from the backend